# get property lambda from property Name (Where property type can be nullable)

Tags: linq, lambda

Hi there I basically need a function with the following signature

```
Expression<Func<T, object>> GetPropertyLambda(string propertyName)
```

I have made a few attempts but the problem arise when the property is nullable
it goes something like this

```
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "arg");

Expression member = Expression.Property(param, propertyName);

//this next section does conver if the type is wrong however
// when we get to Expression.Lambda it throws
Type typeIfNullable = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(member.Type);
if (typeIfNullable != null)
{
    member = Expression.Convert(member, typeIfNullable);
}                       
return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(member, param);
```

The Exception is

> Expression of type
>   'System.Decimal'
>   cannot be used for return type
>   'System.Object'

I would really apreciate some ideas and also why this doesnt work as expected

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually I don't think the problem has anything to do with Nullable types, but rather with value types. Try your method with a property of type `decimal` (not `Nullable<decimal>`) : it will fail the same way.

Have a look at how expression trees are generated for value and reference types (using LinqPad for instance)

- `Expression<Func<T, object>> lambda = x => x.AString;` (reference type)
  => The body is a `MemberExpression`
- `Expression<Func<T, object>> lambda = x => x.ADecimal;` (value type)
  => The body is a `UnaryExpression` with `NodeType = Convert` and `Type = typeof(object)`, and its `Operand` is a `MemberExpression`

I modified your method slightly to take that into account, and it seems to work fine :

```
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "arg");

Expression member = Expression.Property(param, propertyName);

if (member.Type.IsValueType)
{
  member = Expression.Convert(member, typeof(object));
}

return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(member, param);
```